# How would I be able to track Admin SQL

Tags: php, sql

How can I track only the amount of Administrators from a Database that looks like this:

```
table: users

username        title
Glenn       Administrator
Peter       New Member
```

I want to only track the number of Administrators in the database. Here is the code that I am using but I think its missing some code. Here is the code:

```
// Count number of users
$result = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM users WHERE Administrator"); 
$users_count = mysql_num_rows($result); 
// Display the results 
echo $users_count;
```

I think the WHERE is suppose to be wrong. How can I track only the amount count of Administrators where the table is users and the row is title?

Answer (score 3):

> [Please, don't use mysql_* functions in new
> code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-function-in-php)
> They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation
> process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) has begun on it. See
> the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)?
> Learn about [prepared
> statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead,
> and use [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) or
> [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli) - this
> [article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will
> help you decide which.

Your query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE title = 'Administrator'
```

To rewrite your script using `mysqli`:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "database_name");

$sql    = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE title = 'Administrator'";
$result = $mysqli -> query($sql);
$num    = $result -> num_rows;

echo 'Adminstrators found: '.$num;
```

Comment: So we have that copypasta in answers now too?

Comment: Plus the "Please dont use the mysql functions" copypasta... Every question in [tag:php] and [tag:mysql] has it somewhere...